# Deploying Lightning Pages to sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, ant, migration

I am trying to deploy Lightning pages via ANT as below -

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>New_Hire_Module_Record_Page1</members>
    <name>FlexiPage</name>
  </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

But after deploying i am not seeing changes in the org to which i have deployed.
Am i missing anything?

Comment: Did you deployed the profiles with it?

Comment: No I havnt deployed any profile with it...

Comment: How to activate these pages via Ant migration

Comment: Lightning pages are assigned to profiles. So I guess if you don't add the profiles in your deployment, it can't work. Because your newly deployed pages are not assigned to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to activate those pages in the Lightning App Builder.

See following link for more details :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages_activate.htm&type=5